# Java sorting alphabetical order of array

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to sort via alphabetical order, 
I pasted my code snippet below and the issue I'm having.

```
 String[] arr = new String[3];
 arr[0] = config.getfoldersdata() + "." + config.getCars();
 arr[1] = config.getType();
 arr[2] = entry.getVals() ? "Data" : "Entry";
 result.add(arr);
```

I want to sort alphabetically the `.getCars`.

The above code returns `arr` 1-3 in a single line/row. There can be multiple records/rows/line. So I want them to be sorted alphabetically, by what is returned by `.getCars`.

The `.getCars` will return a string.

I have tried the `Arrays.sort()` above, but the `re` is no change in the `result` (no sorting).

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: I would assume that getCars should return the list or cars and not a string.

Comment: Maybe you want to step back and give a "full" example of input data and expected output. Right now I have a really hard time understanding your question.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to sort exactly? And why do you use an array to store three different things. It looks like what you should actually use is an object, with three fields.

Comment: yes sorry, it returns a list. I will paste an example of what I want to sort here.

Comment: foldersdata.toyota                                 example             Entry

Comment: foldersdata.ferrari example Entry

Comment: So, you don't want to sort `arr`, right? You ant to sort `result`which is a list containing multiple arrays of 3 elements, right? First step: don't use arrays. Use a class, containing properties.

Comment: the above is 2 rows which will show as the result, the car name toyota and ferrari. I want to sort alphabetically based on car name, meaning ferrari should appear the line before toyota

Comment: yes correct I want to sort the result

Comment: I need to sort it in this way with the arrays, changing it would impact various other classes. Its been written in this way and I need to fix it

Comment: Please explain your use case properly. if Array.sort(arr) is not working according to your desire result the write your own sorting logic using Comparable class. kindly see sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is awful: the arrays should in fact be objects.

But anyway, you just need a comparator which sorts the array based on their first element's natural ordering:

```
result.sort(Comparator.comparing(array -> array[0]));
```

Comment: Will also take the advise to improve the design, thanks

Answer (score -1):

as far as i know u can't sort in alphabetical order using normal arrays try using tree set like this `TreeSet tree = new TreeSet();` that way it will be sorted in

Comment: The OP probably needs a List and sort it by Collections.sort